# How does Xcode calculate the deployment target for storyboards?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, uistoryboard

For storyboards we can set the "Builds for" value in the File Inspector of Interface Builder. There is a default value, `Deployment Target` which is not correct in my case. (But I would like it to be correct without having to set it as we are creating the whole Xcode project for each build.)

[image]

The storyboard file has the following contents:

```
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15706"/>
        <capability name="Named colors" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
```

And if I change

```
<deployment identifier="iOS"/>
```

to

```
<deployment version="4352" identifier="iOS"/>
```

I get the correct one for my case (iOS 11.0).

But why is the default `10.3` if my build target is `11.0`. (As a matter of fact, `10.3` does not appear in any of the project files.) Can I avoid setting the value explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You may needs reopen the project workspace after changing target's deployment version.

Just test it with Xcode 11.6, it works fine.

BTW

```
<deployment identifier="iOS"/>  // This is the correct one
<deployment version="4352" identifier="iOS"/>  // Don't use this
```